# Correct method to iterate through an array and apply string as an attribute name?

Tags: python, list, csv, arcgis

I have a .csv containing with a large amount of columns and rows. I use python to read the csv and create a table/feature class in ArcGIS and populate the table with the rows from then .csv. I am looking for the best way/shorthand method of the following:

I have a list representing the first row of the .csv "csv_headers".

A short example CSV below shows the list would be:

```
csv_headings = ['Key', 'X', 'Y', 'Value1', 'Value2'...]
```

```
Key        X      Y       Value1    Value2    ...
2221    192934  875767     96.4      95.4
2222    194459  834763     96.3      99.9
2223    193934  905606     90.6      95.1
2224    191974  855100     91.0      95.2
...
```

Currently the following is used to populate the table/feature class in ArcGIS:

```
with open("C:\\path_to_csv.csv", 'rb') as f:
  reader = csv.DictReader(f)
  for row in reader:
    # Create the feature
    feature = cursor.newRow()

    # Add the point geometry to the feature
    vertex = arcpy.CreateObject("Point")
    vertex.X = row['X']
    vertex.Y = row['Y']
    feature.shape = vertex

    # Add attributes
    feature.Key = row['Key']
    feature.X = row['X']
    feature.Y = row['Y']
    feature.Value1 = row['Value1']
    feature.Value2 = row['Value2']
```

My full dataset has 43 columns, and currently is all written in manually as "feature.ValueX = row['ValueX'] for 43 lines, which I am looking to shorten.

Essentially I'd like to iterate through "csv_headers" as x and apply x as both the attribute name and the row title, hypothetically:

```
    # Add attributes

    for x in csv_headers:
      feature.x = row[x]
```

However this will not work, just wondering what the correct way of thinking around this might be? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is:

```
for attr in csv_headings:
    setattr(feature, attr, row[attr])
```

and the `setattr` docs is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr).

Comment: Perfect - short and sweet, thank you. I'd come across getattr and setattr but I used it incorrectly when trying to apply it here.